# Times: Days and Hours in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datetime, timestamp, match

I am traying to select the documents of this collections in MongoDB from Friday at 16:45 to Monday at 7:00 am and also to get the results in descending order according to the value of the measure ("valor" in the document)
The documents in the collections are like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("609c2c2d420a73728827e880"),
"timestamp" : ISODate("2020-07-01T02:15:00Z"),
"sensor_id" : 2,
"location_id" : 1,
"medidas" : [
    {
        "tipo_medida" : "Emision_CO2",
        "valor" : 1.67,
        "unidad" : "gCO2/m2"
    },
    {
        "tipo_medida" : "Consumo_electrico",
        "valor" : 0.00155,
        "unidad" : "kWh/m2"
    }
]
```

}

I wrote the next code:

```
        db.datos_sensores.aggregate([{
 $project:{timestamp: 1,"_id":0, "medidas":{$slice:["$medidas",-1]},"location_id":1}},
{$addFields:{dia_semana:{$dayOfWeek:"$timestamp"},Hora:{$hour:"$timestamp"}}},
{$match:{“dia_semana2:{$in:[1,2,6,7]}, “medidas.tipo_medida”:1,
“location_id”:1}}]).sort({"medidas.1.valor": -1}).pretty()
```

But I do not know how to select hours and minutes (only the days) and I am getting: uncaught exception: SyntaxError: illegal character :

Comment: query looks good see [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/G9DswFmbmAg), but you can not use `.sort()` method with `aggregate()` method, there is a $sort stage for aggregation use `{ $sort: { "medidas.valor": -1 } }`

Comment: Thank you @turivishal for taking the time to answer. And thank you so much for showing me playground, I didn't know the web. I could select the days but can't select times, Fri.16:45 to Mon.7.00; I paste more documents: (https://mongoplayground.net/p/FVnZJGocYJc)

Comment: there are many operators for date and time, use [$dateToString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) you can format in any format..